# Не работает условие, указанное через CDbCriteria в реляционном запросе

Tags: php, yii, activerecord

Есть у меня реляционный запрос без получения связанной модели:

```
$articles = Article::model()->with(array(
                'categories'=>array(
                    'select'=>false,
                    'joinType'=>'INNER JOIN',
                    'condition'=>'categories.id = :catId',
                    'params'=>array(':catId'=>$option),
                    'distinct'=>true,
                ),
            ))->findAll('is_reklama=:isRekl', array(':isRekl'=>1));
```

Если я передаю условие в findAll() как $condition: `findAll('is_reklama=:isRekl', array(':isRekl'=>1))`, то все отлично работает. Если же я передаю через CDbCriteria:

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->condition='is_reklama=:isRekl';
$criteria->params=array(':isRekl'=>1);
...
findAll($condition);
```

, то это условие не срабатывает, хотя, вроде как, должно... Подскажите как правильно сделать с условием в CDbCriteria

Answer (score 1):

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addCondition('is_reklama = :isReklama');
$criteria->params = [
     'isReklama' => 1
];
// Другие условия
...->findAll($criteria);
```